# Ignoring input or delaying the next output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I set an input to delay the next output but I'm getting an error when ignoring the input. Is there a way to ignore an input or another way to delay an output. I would really appreciate the help

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 11, in <module>
    b = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Code:

```
while True:
       print("Tissues")
       print("     Plant tissues")
       print("         Meristametic tissues")
       a = str(input(": "))
       print()
       if a == "Tissues":
           print("A group of cells modified to perform a specific function")
       elif a == "Meristametic tissues":
           print("A group of cells in a tissue that rapidly divides by Mitosis to form new cells")
       b = int(input())
```

Comment: you could delay it using time.sleep()

Comment: Why do you want to delay ?

Comment: an oldschool `input("Press Enter to continue")` maybe?

Comment: Just replace `int(input())` with `input()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delay the input, you should use:

```
import time
time.sleep(<SECONDS>)
```

If you want to skip the given answer you can always use the keyword `continue` in order to move to the next iteration of the loop.
And for the last part - what have you tried to do with the line  `b = int(input())` ?
In order to put the input in the variable `b` you should just remove the `int()` conversion that the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

you can make delay with time module:
`import time` and then add this line of code: `time.sleep(2)` for waiting 2 sec.

and with your code:
you can just ignore the `int()` with the input(). using like this `b = input()` wont raise that error.
Also, you can do this: `input("Press enter to continue...")`

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the input by comparing the entered input with `''`. If the user hit a `newline`, i.e., ignores the input, then the loop will `continue`:

```
while True:
    print("Tissues")
    print("     Plant tissues")
    print("         Meristametic tissues")
    a = str(input(": "))
    print()
    if(a == ''):
        continue

    elif a == "Tissues":
        print("A group of cells modified to perform a specific function")
    elif a == "Meristametic tissues":
        print(
            "A group of cells in a tissue that rapidly divides by Mitosis to form new cells")
    b = int(input())
```